# Pass header parameters with sendRedirect URL

Tags: java, url, http-headers

How to pass header parameters with `sendRedirect` URL?

I am trying to do `sendRedirect` to different application. But I want to pass header parameters along with request. How to do this?

Comment: And what are you efforts ?

Answer (score 8):

`HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()` sends a redirect response(302) to the client. The client then initiates a new request to the resource specified in the `Location` header. HTTP doesn't define a way for a server to ask the client to set any request headers to a redirected resource.

To pass data to the new resource, you could set it in the query string:

To make it concrete

```
response.sendRedirect("NewResource?param1=value1");
```

**NewResource**

```
request.getParameter("param1");
```

Comment: But whats about the client? Would he get the response headers?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it's not possible. It sounds like you want something like this:

```
Client -> ServerA: 
GET /foo

ServerA -> Client: 
301 Moved Permanently
<Something magic to force the client to send header "Header1: xxx" to ServerB>

Client -> ServerB:
GET /bar
Header1: xxx
```

That "something magic" doesn't exist. The client will always send whatever header values it wants to send. There's not even a standard way with a redirect to *suggest* that a client do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines sets the [http headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) to the `response`:

```
    response.setHeader(header1, value1);
    response.setHeader(header2, value2);
     -----
     -----
     response.sendredirect("someJsp.jsp")
```